# About Signextension if I store short data type to int data type in C

Tags: c

I want to know whether sign extension will occur if I store short data type(16bit) to int data type(32bit) in C.
Sign extension means that the upper 16 bit in int data type will be 111111..... or 0000000.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think logically. If an object of the type `short` (16 bits) is assigned to an object of the type `int` (32 bits) then as a result the object of the type `int` shall have the same value that is stored in the object of the type `short`.

That is if the value stored in the object of the type `short` is positive then and the value assigned to the object of the type `int` also shall be positive. And vice versa if the value stored in the object of the type `short` is negative then the value assigned to the object of the type `int` also shall be negative.

So if values of integers are stored in the two-s complement form then the value stored in the object of the type `int` shall be stored also in the 2's complement form. It means that the value of the sign bit is propagated in the object of the type `int` to produce the 2;s complement internal representation.

In other forms of internal representations the mechanism can be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test it and find out, but think about it this way: what will this code do?

```
int16_t x = -1000;
int32_t y = x;
```

Of course `y` will have the value -1000 and not some positive value, so sign extension is indeed what happens.

This assumes you're on a machine with the usual two's complement arithmetic, which surely you are.